# Code stuck when solving Poisson equation with MPI

Tags: parallel-processing, fortran, mpi

I implemented a simple 1D Poisson equation parallel solver with MPI so familiarize myself with the MPI library. I designed the code to run with an unspecified number of processors (including with just 1).

The code runs and yields good results when ran on 1 or 2 processors. However, it gets stuck on the `mpi_send` and `mpi_recv` calls with 4 processors. Therefore, I expect my implementation of the exchange of ghost points is wrong.

As the code is too large to include here, I've only included the Jacobi scheme and the exchange of data:

```
do iter=1,max_iter                                                                                    
    !~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~             
    ! Initial guess, on interior points only                                                          
    Ujacob(min_x+1:max_x-1) = 0._dp                                                                   
    Ujacob_all(0:grid_nx-1) = 0._dp                                                                   

    !~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~             
    ! Store solution vector from last iteration                                                       
    Uold    (:) = Ujacob    (:)                                                                       
    Uold_all(:) = Ujacob_all(:)                                                                       

    !~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~             
    ! Jacobi scheme                                                                                   
    do ii=min_x+1,max_x-1                                                                             
        !Ujacob(ii) = 0.5_dp * (Uold  (ii-1) + Uold  (ii+1) - grid_delta_x**2 * Urhs(ii))             
    end do                                                                                            

    !~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~             
    ! Gather Ujacob vector                                                                            
    call mpi_allgather(Ujacob(0:proc_nx-1), proc_nx, mpi_float,                         &             
                    &  Ujacob_all,          proc_nx, mpi_float, mpi_comm_world, ierror)               

    !~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~             
    ! Compute error and check if less than tolerance value                                            
    error = sqrt((sum(Ujacob_all - Uold_all)**2) / dble(grid_nx))                                     

    if(error < error_tol) return                                                                      
    !~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~             
    ! Exchange data points                                                                            

    ! Interior processors                                                                         
    if(Xsrc /= -1 .AND. Xdes /= -1) then
        call mpi_send(Ujacob(        0), 1, mpi_float, Xsrc, 200, mpi_comm_world, ierror)         
        call mpi_send(Ujacob(proc_nx-1), 1, mpi_float, Xdes, 100, mpi_comm_world, ierror)         

        call mpi_recv(Ujacob(     -1), 1, mpi_float, Xsrc, 100, mpi_comm_world, stat, ierror)     
        call mpi_recv(Ujacob(proc_nx), 1, mpi_float, Xdes, 200, mpi_comm_world, stat, ierror)
    ! First processor                                                                             
    elseif(Xsrc == -1) then                                                                    
        call mpi_send(Ujacob(proc_nx-1), 1, mpi_float, Xdes, 100, mpi_comm_world, ierror)         
        call mpi_recv(Ujacob(proc_nx  ), 1, mpi_float, Xdes, 200, mpi_comm_world, stat, ierror)
    ! Last processor                                                                              
    elseif(Xdes == -1) then                                                                   
        call mpi_send(Ujacob( 0), 1, mpi_float, Xsrc, 200, mpi_comm_world, ierror)                
        call mpi_recv(Ujacob(-1), 1, mpi_float, Xsrc, 100, mpi_comm_world, stat, ierror)          
    end if                                                                                                           
end do
```

`Xsrc` and `Xdes` are set the following way:

```
   !~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 
    ! Setting the source and destination neighbors of each processor                              
    if(myid == 0) then                                                                            
        Xsrc = -1                                                                                 
        Xdes = myid + 1                                                                           
    elseif(myid == nprocs-1) then                                                                 
        Xsrc = myid -1                                                                            
        Xdes = -1                                                                                 
    else                                                                                          
        Xsrc = myid - 1                                                                           
        Xsrc = myid + 1                                                                           
    end if
```

Also, I have checked that the processor rank 0 and `nprocs-1` indeed correspond to the left and right bounded processors.

I have checked that the tags are well set. Also, feel free to comment on anything which you feel may be improved.

Comment: I think it may be useful to see how you set `Xsrc` and `Xdes`.

Comment: @d_1999 Yes you're right, please see edit

Comment: Your halo exchange is conceptually flawed as you rely on `MPI_SEND` being buffered, which might not always be the case. Use `MPI_SENDRECV` to send and receive at the same time without blocking. Also, don't use such a complex logic for sending and receiving. Simply use `MPI_PROC_NULL` instead of `-1` for the non-existing neighbours of the boundary ranks and always execute the sendrecv in both directions. Sending to `MPI_PROC_NULL` or receiving from it is a no-op.

Comment: I think you've got a typo in your last branch from your edit.

Comment: @d_1999 mhm, the error actually came from that typo. I'll delete the question later as it just from a stupid mistake

Comment: @HristoIliev Thanks for the advice, I did not know about `MPI_PROC_NULL`, it does make things simpler. Also, I am using `MPI_WTIME()` before (`t0`) and after (`t1`) my iteration scheme and the difference always returns 0, when clearly it takes a few seconds. When printing both `t0` and `'t1`, they both return values such as `1.4709921E09`. I assume the difference in such big numbers will always be 0. Any way around it?

Comment: Whilst fixing the typo may have solved the problem in your case you should pay attention to the advice of @HristoIliev. You can very easily get into difficulty using the approach that you have picked -- as you're just getting familiar with MPI you probably want to try to learn the correct/best way to do things from the start!

Comment: @d_1999 Yes, I have already set any `Xsrc` or `Xdes` to `MPI_PROC_NULL` of outside the boundary domain. However, running it in parallel seems to be slower than in serial and I am not sure why.

Comment: Regarding the timing issue, MPI_WTIME returns a double-precision value and it is important to store it in a double-precision variable. If you store it in a single-precision variable (e.g. "real") then you may not have enough accuracy to distinguish small time differences.

Comment: I suspect the slowdown is caused by the way you compute the error term - see my comment in the answer I gave. I posted the answer at the same time as you fixed the error yourself but I think the comments in it might still be useful to you.

Comment: Why do you even bother performing the halo exchange when each iteration ends with `MPI_ALLGATHER` and you already have the entire domain gathered at every rank? You should compute the partial error term in each rank then do `MPI_ALLREDUCE` with `MPI_SUM` in order to obtain the global error. Also, do not copy `Ujacob` into `Uold`. Instead, declare the arrays as pointer targets and use pointers to access them. When you have to swap the arrays, simply swap the pointers.

Comment: @HristoIliev I would leave them allocatable and exchange them using `move_alloc()` instead. Pointers can block some optimizations as the compiler might think the old and the new arrays could alias.

Comment: @HristoIliev Yes, you are right. I fixed my typo, used `MPI_PROC_NULL` when defining `Xsrc` and `Xdes` so my exchange of buffer points only consist of two `mpi_sendrecv` calls. I calculate the error on each processor and use `mpi_allreduce` to check if it's below tolerance. However, compared to my code in serial, running in parallel with 2 and 4 processors is 14 and 22 times slower

Comment: @VladimirF, I didn't know about `move_alloc()`, which seems to come from Fortran 2003. One learns new things every single day :)

Comment: @VladimirF So it's faster to move an allocated array and allocate it again than just copying it into a different one?

Comment: Computation is fast, communication - not so. You are not about to see any speedup with small arrays.

Comment: @solalito `move_alloc()` is basically change of a pointer, but for an allocatable array.

Answer (score 3):

@Hristo is correct that your code is conceptually flawed in principle. However, almost every MPI implementation will buffer MPI_Send for a message containing a single real (though of course this is not guaranteed) so this is not the issue with your code.

I think you have mismatched your tags - the edge cases should have the tags reversed:

```
  elseif(Xsrc == -1) then                                                                    
        call mpi_send(Ujacob(proc_nx-1), 1, mpi_float, Xdes, 200, mpi_comm_world, ierror)         
        call mpi_recv(Ujacob(proc_nx  ), 1, mpi_float, Xdes, 100, mpi_comm_world, stat, ierror)
    ! Last processor                                                                              
    elseif(Xdes == -1) then                                                                   
        call mpi_send(Ujacob( 0), 1, mpi_float, Xsrc, 100, mpi_comm_world, ierror)                
        call mpi_recv(Ujacob(-1), 1, mpi_float, Xsrc, 200, mpi_comm_world, stat, ierror)          
    end if
```

A few other comments on the code:

- it is very inefficient to compute the error term with allgather: you should sum up over the local elements only and then compute the global error with MPI_Allreduce;
- you should use MPI_REAL not MPI_FLOAT for a Fortran code;
- I do not see how our code can run on a single process - here the process will execute the first elseif clause then try and send to a non-existent rank.

Once you have checked that your tags are now correct, you should then fix the issues pointed out by @Hristo.

Comment: Actually the tags were right. The main issue was due to a typo when defining `Xsrc` and `Xdes`. I fixed it along with other non-efficient issues I had - see above comments. I do have a question though. What do you mean by "almost every MPI implementation will buffer `MPI_SEND` for a message containing a single real?

Comment: The issue is whether send is synchronous (i.e. doesn't complete until a matching receive is posted) or asynchronous (completes regardless of whether there is matching receive). Ssend is guaranteed synchronous & Bsend guaranteed asynchronous. However, Send can be either. This was the point that @HristoIliev was making - if Send is synchronous then your code will deadlock as all processes are sending and none receiving. Asynchronous send requires making a copy & delivering later on. For small messages MPI typically takes a copy; for large messages there won't be room so it uses synchronous send.